# HTML Email - <table> ISSUE

Tags: html-email, newsletter

is it possible to have two rows in a single table, without using rowspan? I'd like to use more than one tr tags into one single table, to have less tables around the code.

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

two rows in a single table without rowspan..

```
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><Td></td></tr>
</table>
```